# Get Discriminator in Linq Select results

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to make a SQL Query with LinqToEntities which will be as efficient as possible so I would like to avoid iterating after every record I get in results to get a new corrected collection. I'm trying to create a ready collection to send as a result in API just with this one query.

I'm trying to get a discriminator value though with inherited models.

My models are somewhat like these:

```
public abstract class DbEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string DiscriminatorValue
    {
        get
        {
            return ObjectContext.GetObjectType(GetType()).Name;
        }
    }
}

public class Foo : DbEntity {
}

public class Bar: DbEntity {
}
```

This model will create a table in database which will have a column called `Discriminator`. To get the discriminator value I used my custom `DiscriminatorValue` property but it won't work in queries like this:

```
var events = context.MyTable.Select(t => new {
    Discriminator = t.DiscriminatorValue
}).ToList();
```

This below one will obviously work, but it will be much slower imho:

```
var events = context.MyTable.ToList().Select(t => new {
    Discriminator = t.DiscriminatorValue
}).ToList();
```

Is it possible to get `Discriminator` value without having to write my custom `SQL` query myself (like real sql which I know is possible too).

Comment: `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(GetType()).Name;` Why do you need to fetch from the database to get this value?

Comment: I explained in the question - I don't want to iterate through every record to calculate this value with this property. I mean it is a possibilty, but why do I need to calculate this if I have this in database anyway?

Comment: Just run in the same problem. Probably One should not use subclassing in EF at all.